# Gmail API with Attachments

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

How can I send an email message from Apps Script using the Gmail API that picks up a file from the Drive and includes in the message as an attachment.

I've looked in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads) but could not get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this without using the GMail API, using the GmailApp Service instead. In fact, your use case is the example provided in the documentation for [GmailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)).

```js
 // Send an email with a file from Google Drive attached as a PDF.
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 GmailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Please see the attached file.', {
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script'
 });
```